# Invisible dialog window in Eclipse Luna

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Luna with several workspaces and different plugins and frameworks (Grails, plain Java, etc.). Often, when I open a dialog its content is not visible. Sometimes this also happens for context menus. This only happens in Eclipse.

Any idea how to solve this?

[image]